# Refresh UITableView on viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uitableview, viewwillappear

Trying to get my TableView to reload after clicking "back" button.  I've researched, and others recommend putting [self.tableView reloadData] in the viewWillAppear method, but I get an error "Property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'InputsRecap'"  Any help on how I can get this refreshed?

// .h

```
@interface InputsRecap: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{  

NSDictionary *tableContents;
NSArray *sortedKeys;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *tableContents;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *sortedKeys;

@end
```

// table code in .m starts here

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return [self.sortedKeys count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:
                    [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
return [listData count];
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:
                    [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

 UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView
                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] ;
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

// adds arrow to cell
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is your `view` property a `UITableView`?

Comment: Not sure I follow you, but my storyboard is a View Controller then I dropped in a TableView.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the tableView?

Comment: And what property do you have pointing to that table view (or do you not).

Comment: Do not have reference or property to tableView - just set them up as delegate and datasource outlets.

Comment: Okay then you need to reference the tableView.

Comment: Thank you both Rocky and Wain - I just needed to add a reference to the UITableView in my h and synthesize in my m.  Then the [self.tableViewName reload data] worked great.